# What am I getting this error/Why is the connection "timed out"?

Tags: bash, ssh, apache2, 22.04, mysql

I ran the commands listed below to help solve the "Connection timed issue but they did nothing:

```
sudo systemctl status ssh
sudo apt update
audo apt install open-ssh server
```

When I run `ssh user@ipaddress` I get `ssh: connect to host ipaddress port 22: Connection timed out`

Here is the error I receive when I run the file in terminal:

```
./file.sh
Working...
Sending to users's device
ssh: connect to host ipaddress port 22: Connection timed out
abcd
[sudo] password for me:
sudo: a password is required
[sudo] password for me:
Failed to start apache2.service: Unit apache2.service is masked.
Unit rabbitmq-server.service could not be found.
Failed to start rabbitmq-server.service: Unit rabbitmq-server.service not found.
Unit mysql.service could not be found.
Failed to start mysql.service: Unit
```

mysql.service not found.

Here's the file:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Working..."
echo "Sending to users device"
ssh -t -p 22 users@ipadress
echo "abcd"
sudo systemctl status apache2
sudo systemctl start apache2
sudo systemctl status rabbitmq-server
sudo systemctl start rabbitmq-server
sudo systemctl status mysql
sudo systemctl start mysql
```

I'm not sure what to do next. I have tried so many things and they are not working. Is it my code? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Ignore the script. Can you actually connect to the server over ssh?

Comment: I cannot to the server

Comment: Most of the details you added here are not at all relevant to that specific problem. Make this easier on yourself and focus on one problem at a time. If you want your script to connect to some ssh server you need to have access to that server and the ability to connect over ssh. If the command gives an error in your terminal then it will also give you an error in your script. So ignore the script for now and figure out what command you need to access the ssh server. Who administers that server? If it's your server, you need to configure it to accept incoming ssh connection.

Comment: I suggest you go back to the beginning with your research. You need to determine how to connect to this particular ssh server if you need that as part of your script.  A script will not work if its parts do not work individually.